# How to use spark with existing Hadoop 2.x

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

We have Hadoop 2.5 already installed on a server. Is it possible to use that Hadoop to deploy Spark programs? I want Spark to use the existing Yarn to schedule tasks and be able to read and write to the existing HDFS. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

you can try using Apache Spark pre-built downloads available
https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

[image]

If thats not working out then you need to build the spark by adding your hadoop jars 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html
Its easy

Your Spark can then directly access your HDFS by adding your config in spark-default config.
check all the configurations available in Spark

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Your Spark can run in YARN as well as Local model
-https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

> You need not to make any new changes in your existing hadoop Setup to
>   make spark work , you just need to configure everything in your Spark
>   .

Comment: a small addendum to this answer: you can run SPARK as: 1. standalone 2. on mesos cluster, 3. on hadoop cluster 4. (i forgot:) )